# Concise way of saying "A list of things"

Tags: translation, word-choice

Thinking from the point of view of an URL/Blog/Page Title. I wish to say `A list of things` or `My list of things.`

I am not sure whether `Dingeliste` is accurate and concise at the same time. Another word that my limited German vocabulary tells me is `MeinerDingeList`

Does this sound natural to a german speaker? <s>Is the capitalisation proper?</s>

EDIT: I have posted the Camel Case usage, because I want to register and share the URL. Its easier to remember Camel Casing, hence the reason.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? (Would "A list of things" be your page title? + What are you listing?)  "Thing" is not entirely equivalent to "Ding".

Comment: Both variants are utterly unnatural. And no, camel case is not proper capitalization in German, or any language for that matter. Anyway, a native speaker would say "Meine Sachen". As a title for a blog, "Meine Siebensachen" could be even better. But as others have said, it is not clear what you are really after, so it's next to impossible to make good suggestions. We can't even so much as say if you really mean *Dinge, Sachen* or *Zeug*.

Comment: @Carlster I was just trying create a blog with a list of things. You know, list of things people do stuck in traffic, list of things people do in a particular TV series, and so on.

Comment: @RegDwight I have commented above, my exact reason for the name. Also, I will make an edit regarding the Camel Casing.

Comment: @theTuxRacer: Do you plan different urls with different lists of things or just one without specifying your topic? Is SEO relevant?

Comment: Note that for things you'd *do* you would not use "Dinge" but "Sachen". "Dinge" are always objects, while "Sachen" are more general: "Was machst du schon wieder für Sachen?", "35 Sachen bei Schwerelosigkeit zu machen"

Comment: @hellcode SEO is not important. I will not create different url for lists. It will be <german-name>.<service>.com

Answer (score 5):

As @marstato already mentioned, your suggestions do not sound natural and like @RegDwight mentioned camel case is not proper capitalization in German (unless we write source code).

And I don't think that an unspecific "Liste meiner Dinge" is a good choice for a title or headline.

If you mean a list with the top 10 reasons for a specific topic then you could build a specific headline like "Die 10 (besten) Gründe für/weshalb/warum [your topic]". This is not concise but this is how it is mostly done to have an interesting title.

---

EDIT: Now we know it should be a more or less short term used for only one subdomain name regardless of any topic. I don't think that we have a good short term in German that implies your "list of things". So I advice just a lowercase version of Sammelsurium = "sammelsurium.yourdomain.com" (mingle-mangle, similar to "Kram" or "Mischmasch"), because it sounds better than "Dinge", "Sachen" or "Liste" or any combinations of these, but it's unfortunately still unspecific and not the same as your english term.

Comment: I have made an edit regarding the reason behind opting for Camel Casing. Thanks for replying!

Comment: I think `Sammelsurium` is a really good term for this.

Comment: "it's unfortunately still unspecific and not the same as your english term" - arguably, a "list of things" isn't infinitely less unspecific in English, either.

Answer (score 4):

`Dingeliste` does not sound really natural. `Meiner Dinge List` would mean something like "the smartness of my things" which misses the point (and is rather oldspoken).

I would go with `Liste meiner Dinge` or, if the fact that your content is a list is not important with `Meine Dinge`.

Comment: Imho, your examples do not fit the scope anymore (specified in the comments above).

Comment: I agree, @hellcodes answer is more appropriate.

Comment: You can still improve your answer!

Answer (score 0):

While being an old question, I would like to add the following:

1. "Liste meiner Dinge" is pointing a German more to physical things you own, not you or people ususually do.
2. Concerned an URL, camel casing is absolutely not wrong IMHO, because it makes reading easier. But it makes writing error-prone, so make sure to have the same url with only lower casing :-)
3. I would have gone with "Verrückte Verhaltensweisen", "Verrückte Dinge, die wir tun" or something similar.